# Apache 2.2 reverse proxy not working with webservice

Tags: apache2, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up my apache (version 2.2) to work as reverse proxy. I configured apache as shown bellow :

```
LoadModule proxy_module      modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule headers_module    modules/mod_headers.so
LoadFile   /usr/lib/libxml2.so
LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so

<IfModule  proxy_module>

<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyRequests Off 
ProxyPreserveHost On

#ProxyPass /lala http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP?wsdl

ProxyPass /lala http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP
ProxyPassReverse /lala  http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP?wsdl /wsdl

ProxyPass /wsdl http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP?wsdl
ProxyPassReverse /wsdl  http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP?wsdl

</IfModule>
```

Everything is fine when I'm trying to reach an url on a browser, the problem happens when I tried to test a webservice by using SoapUi, for example :

I want to go `http://myServer/lala to proxy http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP`

the same for wsdl

I want to go

```
http://myServer/wsdlto proxy http://myServer:8080/webserviceInterceptorSpring/services/wsInterceptorSOAP?wsdl
```

but soapult is not able to load wsdl from the url `http://myServer/wsdl` launching the following error :

```
Error loading [http://myServer/wsdl]: java.lang.Exception: Failed to load url; http://myServer/wsdl, 0
```